# Receiving incoming email: Google AppEngine PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, email

Per the instructions (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/mail/), I'm expecting that when users send email to a configured email address, my designated script will get invoked with POST fields containing the data from the email. I have gotten it set up so that my script is being invoked BUT ... the $_POST array is empty. (The "else" block below is getting executed.)

The code:

```
if ($_POST) {
   $email = $_POST['sender'];
   $content = $_POST['original'];
   $subject = $_POST['subject'];
}
else {
   syslog(LOG_ERR, "[handle_incoming_email.php] EMPTY POST fields... Bailing.");
   return;
}
```

Any ideas on why this might be?

Thanks so much.
Liz

Comment: Could be a bug - Can you add the contents of $_SERVER? Perhaps open an issue in the App Engine issue tracker as well?

Comment: Stuart, I'm much grateful for you. I hadn't thought to file a bug.
Can you see the output of SERVER here? https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=10280

Comment: Solution from another thread... The email contents are in the POST *body* not the parameters...

$email_body = file_get_contents('php://input');

Comment: @liz, right -- so can you please post this as a self-answer and accept it, to satisfy stackoverflow's normal etiquette? Thanks!